# rspec with autotest-rails duplicating tests in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm using rspec tests with shoulda matchers and autotest-rails. See gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

I haven't changed any config whatsoever on these, and when I run autotest, or just plain old rspec in terminal, the tests rFinished in 1.72 seconds

```
Finished in 1.72 seconds
188 examples, 0 failures

Finished in 1.72 seconds
188 examples, 0 failures
```

When I have tests failing, it prints out details for each one, then does it all again. It is really driving me nuts, does anyone have any ideas on what might be the problem? I can only one find one other example online of someone with this problem, but the fix was relating to guard which i'm not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake... I looked in my global .rspec and it had:

```
--color                                                                                                                                                       
--format doc                                                                                                                                                  
--color                                                                                                                                                       
--format doc
```

The bash script that set up my dev environment for me must have run twice and appended my options twice!